# Windowing Kafka Connect Memgraph

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, memgraphdb, memgraph

Following the [instructions](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka) to integrate Kafka in Memgraph, I realised, that the [Source Connector](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#configure-memgraph) doesn't implement a window functionality. The

> "neo4j.streaming.property": "timestamp",
> "neo4j.streaming.from": "LAST_COMMITTED"

properties are set, but there is no restriction in the query assuring this behavior. For example, at Neo4j, the [Source Instance](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka/quickstart-connect/#_configure_source_instance) can be configured with a *$lastCheck* restriction in the source query, to guarantee that only newly inserted vertices are considered. When running the [Memgraph Source](https://memgraph.com/docs/data-streams/kafka#configure-memgraph), the same *SensorData* nodes are printed into *my-topic* over and over again. I tried implementing a *$lastCheck*-restriction, but the source immediately fails. Am I missing something?